# Spring Boot join in criteria builder

Tags: spring-boot, criteria

i have 2 entities with OneToOne relation

my problem is  i want to add an if to query with codiCanal from entity Canal as parameter .

**Solicitud entity**

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "solicitud_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "solicitud_sequence", allocationSize = 1, name = "solicitud_seq")
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false, name = "id_solicitud")
private Integer idSolicitud;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="codiCanal")
private Canal canal;
private Date dataInici;
private Date dataActualizacio;
private String idFactura;
private String estatSolicitud;
```

**Canal entity**  :

```java
@Id
private String codiCanal;
private String nom;
private Integer idBanc;
```

this is my criteria builder function

```java
@Override
public List<Solicitud> getSoliWithobject(Solicitud object, Pageable pageable) {
    List<Solicitud> solicitudes = soliRepo.findAll((Specification<Solicitud>) (root, cq, cb) -> {
        Predicate p = cb.conjunction();
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(object.getIdFactura())) {
            p = cb.and(p, cb.equal(root.get("idFactura"), object.getIdFactura()));
        }

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(object.getDataInici()) ) {
            p = cb.and(p, cb.between(root.get("dataInici"), object.getDataInici(),currentDate));
        }

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(object.getEstatSolicitud())) {
            p = cb.and(p, cb.equal(root.get("estatSolicitud"), object.getEstatSolicitud()));
        }´
return p;
    }, pageable).getContent();
    return solicitudes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This condition solved my problem:

```
if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(object.getCanal())) {
    p = cb.and(p, cb.equal(root.join("canal").get("codiCanal"), object.getCanal().getCodiCanal()));
}
```